# Error Creating Control - Calendarextender3 Unknown server tag 'ajax:CalendarExtender'

Tags: c#, ajax, calendarextender

While I am working with ajax calender it showing error like  "Error Creating Control - Calendarextender3Unknown server tag 'ajax:CalendarExtender' ". May i know why it is like this ?

```
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"   
 tagPrefix="ajax"
%>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
TagPrefix="ajax" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                <font size="4"><b> EMPLOYEE RESIGNATION</font></b>
                </div>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">

                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
                        <table class="ui-accordion" align="center">

                            <tr>

                                <td align="left" class="style2">
                                    Delete Date</td>
                                <td >
                                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" /> 

                               <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="Calendarextender3" 
         TargetControlID ="txtdate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server">    
         </ajax:CalendarExtender> 

                                </td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>

                        </fieldset>
                </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Myself found answer for this question. Download ajax toolkit dll and add this into toolbox.
then select toolkitscriptmanager and ajax calanderextender from toolbox. sample code below

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
      <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">  
 </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

 <tr>
 <td align="left" class="style2">
 <asp:Label ID="lb3" runat="server" Text="Delete Date"></asp:Label>
</td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtto1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID 
 ="txtfrom1" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server">
 </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>  

 </td>
 </tr>
 </form>
```